# Displaying a DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, phpmyadmin

'An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

Even though I have no errors according to C#. My program will keep displaying this error message when I try to run the program. Can some help?

Comment: The error says exactly what the problem is `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'` Check that you have internet / network accsess.

Comment: Btw when you write a question the title of the question / topic of it should relate to the question you ask. It may be that the error occurs during your attempts to display a datatable BUT the content of the question itself has nothing to do with a datatable at all. (also where possible try to give examples or pieces of code they often help with the finer details when a problem is a bit ambigious)

Comment: in order to get any feasible help you need to please show existing code, what you have tried, and tell use where in the code the error is being raised.. use the `Debugger` also.
if you are not familiar how to configure a connection string here is a site that will show you examples of how to do this in C# .NET 
[C# Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: I've just clicked on what the issue is. The connection is fine. The error is the university server can't be accessed outside uni. But this helped me realise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As is stated in a comment: The error is that the connection to the MySQL host cannot be created (could be wrong password, wrong username, wrong serverip, wrong port being used, .... or that the mysql server is not running at all, ... thus these are the things you should check first).

Another thing is that you sounded confused that the compilation did not show any errors. You can think of it this way: When you compile the syntax and the grammatics are checked if they are ok and appropriate errors shown. BUT what values are there during a run is NOT checked. That is what is done during a run and causes the error you asked about.

Thus compilation does only check if the syntax is correct not if you really manage to connect to soemthing or if the values you are storing in the variables are the ones you expect there to be.